# Use custom logic in EF Code First migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing Database with a some amount of data (i.e. DB is not empty). Now I made a decision to encrypt some sensitive data. I have a column `TemplateBlocks : string`. I'm going to replace it with new column `TemplateBlocksEnc : byte[]` and I did properly changed my Code First model. Then I generated migration and ... stuck!

```
public partial class EncryptTemplateBlocks : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Devices", "TemplateBlocksEnc", c => c.Binary(nullable: true));

        // TODO: read TemplateBlocks data, encrypt, save to new column

        AlterColumn("dbo.Devices", "TemplateBlocksEnc", c => c.Binary(nullable: false));
        DropColumn("dbo.Devices", "TemplateBlocks");
    }

    public override void Down() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Of course, I do not plan to lose any existing data, I need to read all data from old column, encrypt it, store to newly created column and only then I can drop old column.

Is it possible? I guess that I need somehow to get the current connection/transaction, but I have no idea how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Sql` and transact-sql:

```
public partial class EncryptTemplateBlocks : DbMigration {
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Devices", "TemplateBlocksEnc", c => c.Binary(nullable: true));

    // TODO: read TemplateBlocks data, encrypt, save to new column
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.Devices SET TemplateBlocksEnc = ufn_Func(TemplateBlocks) WHERE TemplateBlocksEnc IS NULL");

    AlterColumn("dbo.Devices", "TemplateBlocksEnc", c => c.Binary(nullable: false));
    DropColumn("dbo.Devices", "TemplateBlocks");
}

public override void Down() { /* ... */ }
}
```

you also have the create a Transact-sql version of the encryption or use sql standard encryption.

ufn can be created with n `Sql` call.

Comment: AFAIK, standart SQL encryption does not work well with EF Code First. I mean that I can't get already decrypted model, but need to decrypt every value through SQL query, which is not acceptable in my case. Seems, that CLR UDF is the only way... sad.

Comment: never read about code first AND T-SQL encryption. But AFAIK, you can code everything in T-SQL, not often need CLR UDF. What encryption are you planning ?

Comment: I want to use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` with a key stored in a named key container as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca5htw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: did you give a try to [ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186950.aspx) or [ENCRYPTBYCERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188061.aspx)

Comment: No, I don't, but it does not look too promising. It looks impossible to create an asymmetric key from the key container. It means that I need to have somewhere on the workstation the file with key parameters to create the asymmetric key during migration.